# Limit no of items can select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a code that allows only 5 icons to select, so far i was able to write a code that changes the color of selected icon (image: icon 1 and icon 2), others remain grey until they are selected, now i want to limit the selection to only 5 icons and then user cant click on icons.

The code for icon is

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-1 icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-network btn-facebook" data-status="1"  onclick="" title="FaceBook">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                </a>
                <p class="pt-1 pb-2 m-0">FaceBook</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-1 icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-network btn-instagram btn-invalid" data-status="1"  onclick="" title="Instagram">
                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
                <p class="pt-1 pb-2 m-0">Instagram</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 col-sm-1 icon">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-network btn-linkedin btn-invalid" data-status="1"  onclick="" title="LinkedIn">
                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                </a>
                <p class="pt-1 pb-2 m-0">LinkedIn</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

The code is use to select icons

```
    <script>
        $('.btn-network').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('btn-selected');
            });
    </script>
```

the design
[![Selected icons are in color, non selected ones are in grey][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ysqj.png

this is something similar i want,but i want to do it for icons instead on checkboxes. : http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/

Edit: i also want to display a DIV below, basically what i need is;
user can select upto 5 social media icons and then they will see a box below (activates/displays after selection) to enter user's social profile link.

NOT IMPORTANT: preferably adding new class to disabled icons (ex: disabled) so i can change the color of the icon for disabled ones

can you help please?

thank you

Comment: Where is the code where you tried to limit "selected" to 5?

Comment: hi thanks for the comment, im still trying to figure out that part. i have edited the question with more helpful information. br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the length of selected icons before toggling class

```
const limit = 5;
$('.btn-network').click(function() {
  if($(this).parent().siblings().children('.btn-selected').length < limit) {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, this did not work for me for some reason.

Comment: yes, because of the changed HTML structure. try this if($(this).parent().siblings().children('.btn-selected').length < limit)

Comment: Thank you friend it worked, any idea how to do the second part? displaying a DIV after selection?

Comment: You can create DIV dynamically with JS or toggle visibility of DIV you want to display